# Unable to write to ntfs folder other than the owner

Tags: permissions, ntfs-3g

I've mounted a ntfs partition with ntfs-3g and created a `.NTFS-3G/UserMapping` under root of the partition. I'm unable to create a file inside a folder as a user other than the owner of the folder.

```bash
Necktwi$ sudo runuser -u transmission -- touch /mnt/my_ntfs_drive/some_folder/test
touch: setting times of '/mnt/my_ntfs_drive/some_folder/test': Permission denied
Necktwi$ ls -ld /mnt/my_ntfs_drive/some_folder/
drwxrwxrwx 1 Necktwi Necktwi 131072 Sep 10 19:07 /mnt/my_ntfs_drive/some_folder/
Necktwi$ touch /mnt/my_ntfs_drive/some_folder/test  # no issue
Necktwi$ sudo runuser -u transmission -- id -Gn                      
transmission Necktwi
```

Comment: `man mount` -> `uid=1000,fmask=0133,dmask=0022`

Comment: i want to use usermapping instead making everything writable by user 1000

Comment: NTFS (Windows) permissions and ownerships are completely alien to Linux, which fakes them up as best it can. Whatever user mounts an NTFS partition owns all the files and directories by default.

Comment: when a file is created using ntfs-3g, what windows uid/gid/sid is assigned to the file? If we open this file properties in windows, what SID does it report?